# Not being able of remove redundant records in an Orange.data.Table object

Tags: python, orange, ipython

Per the data type documentation this object should support the remove_duplicates method.
http://orange.biolab.si/docs/latest/reference/rst/Orange.data.table.html

I am trying to remove duplicated records in a Python Script

```
if isinstance(in_data, Orange.data.Table):
   in_data.remove_duplicates()
   out_data = in_data
```

but I keep getting the error:

`AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'remove_duplicates'`

I am missing something? I am using Orange version 3.2

Thanks, Pedro.

Comment: Looking at that documentation, those methods are for `Orange.data` not `Orange.data.Table`. Their return type is `Orange.data.Table`

Comment: Hi Lafexlos, thanks for the comment, but that page is for Orange.data.Table class, not for the whole Orange.data module. Also,  remove_duplicates returns None not a data table. Thanks, Pedro.

Comment: Oh. Holy... I have no idea what was I thinking when writing that braindead comment. Sorry, really.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the old documentation (that is for Python/Orange 2). Here's the proper one for Orange 3: http://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/data-mining-library/reference/data.table.html

However, remove_duplicates method is not available anymore in Orange 3, so I suggest you go with:

```
import itertools
unique = [k for k,g in itertools.groupby(sorted(items))]
```